# PC Speakers RFI. Is it still a thing?

Tags: audio, speakers

I considering buy a logitech z213 to replace my really old edifier (about six years old).

To edifier use to get some interference. They call it [RFI](http://www.stevelarkins.freeuk.com/computer_interference.htm) apparently.

So I googled to find out if z213 has the same problem. All the info I found about interference and PC Speakers are a few years old at least...

Is there a way to know beforehand if this z213 is shielded therefore impervious to this problem. (By the way, is that assumption correct?)

My feeling is that I found nothing recent about it because it is no longer a thing. But that can be some sort of confirmation bias only... =P

So, are all PC Speakers better now? Should I worry about RFI on this z213? What to do about it besides buying them and finding out?

ALSO:

This questions is an example of my problem with the edifier: [There appears to be a poltergeist in my speakers (no, really)](https://superuser.com/questions/192061/there-appears-to-be-a-poltergeist-in-my-speakers-no-really)
And it is quite old...

Comment: RFI is no longer a thing.  The physical laws of the universe were repealed on December 31, 2015, so they don't apply anymore.  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234 I knew it! I felt an awakening... =P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No analog speakers are impervious to EMI and RFI.  You can limit the effects of these "poltergeists" by using the shortest allowable cables, setting your motherboard to use spread spectrum, and not living underneath radio stations or at 55 Central Park West.  Newer speakers generally do have better shielding, but like all things you get what you pay for.  Older more expensive speakers will have better shielding and sound quality even compared to new cheap speakers of today.

My experience with the Z213 setup is that it is of good build quality and the cables are relatively thick compared to cheaper alternatives.  They are a stereo setup so some shielding/grounding can be expected, but I cannot find any technical documentation affirming that claim.  However if the fault lies in the PC itself, no analog speakers will be able to rectify the problem.
Digital audio connection or a shielded audio card, however, will.